# seleccionar fecha igual o menor a al año 1998 - react - native

Tags: react-native

buen dia, tengo un selector de fechas "DatePicker" "https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-date-picker", la cual se muestra sin problemas y permite seleccionar mes, día y año hasta ahí bien, **pero necesito que me deje seleccionar el año hasta 1998 que no se pueda seleccionar un año superior a ese pero no lo he logrado hacer, si alguien me pudiera colaborar se los agradecería.**

```js
import React from 'react'
import DatePicker from 'react-native-date-picker';

const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
const [fechaFormato, setFechaFormato] = useState('Día/Mes/Año');

const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

const formatFecha = fecha => {
  setDate(fecha);
  const dia = fecha.getDate();
  const mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1;
  const anio = fecha.getFullYear();
  setFechaFormato(`${dia}/${mes}/${anio}`);
};

const borrar = () => {
  return (
    <View>
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={() => setOpen(true)}>
           
        <Text> {fechaFormato} </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>


<DatePicker
locale={'es'}
title="Seleccionar fecha"
confirmText="Confirmar"
cancelText="Cancelar"


modal
open={open}
mode="date"
date={date}
onConfirm={date => {
  setOpen(false);
  formatFecha(date);
}}
onCancel={() => {
  setOpen(false);
}}
/>

</View>
  )
}



export default borrar
```

Answer (score 0):

Agregue en DataPicker `maximumDate={new Date('1998-12-31')}` para que solo me dejara seleccionar hasta besa fecha .

```js
import React from 'react'
import DatePicker from 'react-native-date-picker';

//fecha que aparece por defecto
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date('1990-12-31'));
const [fechaFormato, setFechaFormato] = useState('Día/Mes/Año');

const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

const formatFecha = fecha => {
  setDate(fecha);
  const dia = fecha.getDate();
  const mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1;
  const anio = fecha.getFullYear();
  setFechaFormato(`${dia}/${mes}/${anio}`);
};

const borrar = () => {
  return (
    <View>
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={() => setOpen(true)}>
           
        <Text> {fechaFormato} </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>


<DatePicker
//fecha maxima para seleccionar
maximumDate={new Date('1998-12-31')}
locale={'es'}
title="Seleccionar fecha"
confirmText="Confirmar"
cancelText="Cancelar"


modal
open={open}
mode="date"
date={date}
onConfirm={date => {
  setOpen(false);
  formatFecha(date);
}}
onCancel={() => {
  setOpen(false);
}}
/>

</View>
  )
}



export default borrar
```